# How to Build Border dynamically in excel using java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So in my java class I have the following code.

```
int rowNum = 11;
        Row myRow = null;
        Cell myCell = null;
        for (Object obj : details) {
            Object[] objArr = (Object[]) obj;
            String header = "";
            String value = "";
if (objArr[0] != null) {
                header = objArr[0].toString();
                myRow = sheet.createRow((short) rowNum);
                myCell = myRow.createCell(1);
                myCell.setCellValue(header);
 }

if (objArr[1] != null) {
                value = objArr[1].toString();
                myCell = myRow.createCell(6);
                myCell.setCellValue(value);
                myCell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
    rowNum++;
        }
```

and for border

```
for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
            Cell columnHeaderCell = myRow.createCell(i);
            columnHeaderCell.setCellValue((Double) objArr[i]);
            columnHeaderCell.setCellStyle(columnHeaderStyle);

        }
```

The problem is the border is over lapping on top of the data and is creating border for all the cells.
How do i create a 2 X 10*(x) table dynamically in java?

Comment: Which Library you are using? This is possible with JXL. You can refer th the `jxl.format.Color` for making cells and borders color.

Comment: I'm using Apache POI (HSSF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by doing the following. Getting the data's as object. So for empty cells, validating for ***object!=null***.

***My Code:***

```
int rowNum = 1;
Row myRow = null;
Row emptyRow = null;
Cell myCell = null;
Cell emptyCell =null;

for (Object obj : details) {
            Object[] objArr = (Object[]) obj;
            String header = "";
            String value = "";


            if(objArr[0]==null){
                emptyRow = sheet.createRow((short) rowNum);
                emptyCell = emptyRow.createCell(0);
                emptyCell.setCellValue("");
                emptyCell.setCellStyle(style);
            }

            if(objArr[1]==null){
                emptyCell = emptyRow.createCell(1);
                emptyCell.setCellValue(value);
                emptyCell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
```

For building Rows dynamically with borders:

***Building Header Column:***

```
if (objArr[0] != null) {
                header = objArr[0].toString();

                myRow = sheet.createRow((short) rowNum);
                myCell = myRow.createCell(0);



                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    Cell columnHeaderCell = myRow.createCell(i);
                    columnHeaderCell.setCellValue("");
                    columnHeaderCell.setCellStyle(style);   
                }
    }
```

***For building Value Column:***

```
    if (objArr[1] != null) {
                value = objArr[1].toString();
                myCell = myRow.createCell(1);
                myCell.setCellValue(value);
                myCell.setCellStyle(style);
            }

            rowNum++;
        }
```

The above parenthesis is for closing `for each` loop.

***For Border***

```
   HSSFCellStyle style=wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Apache POI the borders can be set as below.
Find below sample, which might help you.

```
/* Create Workbook and Worksheet */
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Colored Cell Border");
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

/* Set Borders thickness */            
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);             
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);            
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);              
style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);

/* Get Color Index */
style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

/* Add border color to a cell */
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);                
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Different border colors for a Cell");                
cell.setCellStyle(my_style);
```

Comment: This is for one cell. I'm building a table dynamically, which has around 20+ rows and 2 columns. When I try to loop it, the border is over lapping the data's printed.